# Где лежит settings.jar в PhpStorm на macOS?

Tags: macos, phpstorm, jetbrains

Хочу заинпортить все настройки, сниппеты из PhpStorm в Intellij, но не могу найти файл settings.jar. Его нет в директории, куда предлагает зайти Intellij по дефолту
Где они лежит у вас?

Comment: Нигде. Такого файла в поставке нет. Он создается при вызове File | Export Settings. Если вы никогда раньше не экспортировали настройки, такого файла у вас, скорее всего, нет

Comment: @lena спасибо! Перенесите в ответы, что бы я отметил ответ ответом :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такого файла в поставке нет. Он создается при вызове `File | Export Settings`. Если вы никогда раньше не экспортировали настройки, такого файла у вас, скорее всего, нет.
Попробуйте в PHPStorm вызвать `File | Export Settings`, а потом в IDEA импортировать созданный файл через `File | Import Settings`